# Deduct formula for adjugate tensor

Tags: tensors, cross-product, adjoint-operators, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to decuct the formula:

$\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})_{ij} = 0.5 \epsilon_{ipq} \epsilon_{jrs} T_{pr} T_{qs}$

from the definition:

$\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})(\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}) = (\mathbf{T} \mathbf{u}) \times (\mathbf{T} \mathbf{v})$

where $\mathbf{T}$ is an arbitray second order Tensor and $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ are arbitray vectors, $\times$ is the cross product and the dot product between a second order Tensor and a vector is denoted by $\mathbf{T} \mathbf{v}$.

I am stuck at this point:

$\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})_{om} u_i v_j \epsilon_{ijm} = T_{ij} T_{kl} \epsilon_{iko} u_j v_l$

and I don't know how to get rid of u and v to get the required formula?

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own answer.

Denoting the dot product between 2 Vectors by $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}$.

The cross product between 2 orthogonal basevectors can be written as follows:

$\mathbf{e}_r \times \mathbf{e}_s = \epsilon_{rsp} \mathbf{e}_p$

multiplying both sides by $\epsilon_{jsr}$ yields:

$ \epsilon_{jsr} \mathbf{e}_r \times \mathbf{e}_s = \epsilon_{jsr}\epsilon_{rsp} \mathbf{e}_p$

And since $\epsilon_{jsr}\epsilon_{rsp} = \delta_{js} \delta_{sp} - \delta_{jp}\delta_{ss} $

$\mathbf{e}_j = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{jrs} \mathbf{e}_r \times  \mathbf{e}_s$

Using this the ij compenent of $\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})$ can be deducted:

$\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})_{ij} = \mathbf{e}_i  \cdot (\text{adj}(\mathbf{T}) \mathbf{e}_i )=  \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{jrs} \mathbf{e}_i \cdot ((\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})(\mathbf{e}_r \times  \mathbf{e}_s))$

The above given defintion holds for arbitary vectors and therefore also for orthogonal basevectors. Therefore:

$(\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})(\mathbf{e}_r \times  \mathbf{e}_s)) = (\mathbf{T} \mathbf{e}_r) \times (\mathbf{T}\mathbf{e}_s)$

$\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})_{ij} =  \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{jrs} \mathbf{e}_i \cdot ((\mathbf{T} \mathbf{e}_r) \times (\mathbf{T}\mathbf{e}_s))$

Calculating the dot and cross products yields the wanted result:

$\text{adj}(\mathbf{T})_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}  \epsilon_{ipq} \epsilon_{jrs} T_{pr} T{qs}$